# Error on updating packages in npm

Tags: npm, npm-publish

I get this error when updating my package.

> "cannot be republished until 24 hours have passed" in nodejs

Answer (score 16):

Your package was most likely unpublished with [npm-unpublish](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/unpublish).
If it is so, you can publish your package again only after 24 hours.

Comment: In my case, I didn't unpublish the whole package. I only unpublished one version, which was the only version. And now I see the same error message :(

Comment: Same happened to me. Unpublished a specific - and the only - version and now I have to wait 24 hours.

Comment: https://github.com/npm/rfcs/discussions/355 change request to give a warning

Comment: Just happened to me as well .. unpublished the first and only version of a package. Damn.

Answer (score 6):

This will happen after you unpublished all versions with [npm-unpublish](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/unpublish). e.g.:

```
npm unpublish <package-name> -f
```

Sadly they do not warn you even if you just removed the last version e.g.:

```
npm unpublish <package-name>@<version>
```

after 24 hours it should work anyway.

I created a [change request](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/discussions/355) to give a warning about that.

Comment: as of version 8.3.1 a pull request to fix this with a warning has been accepted, see: https://github.com/npm/cli/pull/4191